# how to handle onClick event with multiple component with the same class name in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.js and I want to apply the toggle feature at 'place-box' by using 'isOpen' state and my intention is it only works when I click single place-box div so I added onClick event at 'place-box' div. but all of the elements are toggled at the same time.

I guess it's because they all have the same class name.
how can I fix this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { FETCH_CITIES_QUERY } from "../../server/Data/RentQueries";
import PlaceResult from "../Rent/PlaceResult";

const CityResult = (props) => {
  const [placeId, setPlaceId] = useState();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FETCH_CITIES_QUERY, {
    variables: { cityName: cityName },
  });

  const showPlaceInfo = (placeId, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPlaceId(placeId);
    setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.cities.map((city) => {
          return (
            <div className="city-box">
              {city.places.map((place) => {
                return (
                  // this is place-box div and I added onClick event here
                  <div
                    className="place-box"
                    key={place.id}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      showPlaceInfo(place.id, e);
                    }}
                  >
                    <li className="place-name">{place.name}</li>
                    {isOpen && (
                      <PlaceResult className="place-indiv" placeId={placeId} />
                    )}
                    {!isOpen && (
                      <div className="place-info-box">
                        <li>{place.address}</li>
                        {conditionCheck(city.condition)}
                        <li>{place.phone}</li>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CityResult;
```

[image]

[image: This is what it's like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `isOpen` is used for all cities. If you change `isOpen` to `true` all place-boxes are opened. You should store the `id` of the currently opened city inside a variable and compare against it to check if the current city in the for loop should be opened.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { FETCH_CITIES_QUERY } from "../../server/Data/RentQueries";
import PlaceResult from "../Rent/PlaceResult";

const CityResult = (props) => {
  const [placeId, setPlaceId] = useState();
  const [openedPlaceId, setOpenedPlaceId] = useState(undefined);
    
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FETCH_CITIES_QUERY, {
    variables: { cityName: cityName },
  });

  const showPlaceInfo = (placeId, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPlaceId(placeId);
    setOpenedPlaceId(placeId);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.cities.map((city) => {
          return (
            <div className="city-box">
              {city.places.map((place) => {
                return (
                  // this is place-box div and I added onClick event here
                  <div
                    className="place-box"
                    key={place.id}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      showPlaceInfo(place.id, e);
                    }}
                  >
                    <li className="place-name">{place.name}</li>
                    {openedPlaceId === place.id && (
                      <PlaceResult className="place-indiv" placeId={placeId} />
                    )}
                    {!(openedPlaceId === place.id) && (
                      <div className="place-info-box">
                        <li>{place.address}</li>
                        {conditionCheck(city.condition)}
                        <li>{place.phone}</li>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CityResult;
```

This way only the clicked place will be opened.

Comment: I had no clue how to handle. Thanks a lot!